# Asp.Net debugging using windbg/PSSCOR2

Tags: asp.net, debugging, windbg

I run the finalize queue command in windbg, I got the below results:

```
0:121> !finalizequeue
SyncBlocks to be cleaned up: 0
MTA Interfaces to be released: 0
STA Interfaces to be released: 0
----------------------------------
generation 0 has 9 finalizable objects (150a70a8->150a70cc)
generation 1 has 4 finalizable objects (150a7098->150a70a8)
generation 2 has 187422 finalizable objects (14ff0020->150a7098)
Ready for finalization 0 objects (150a70cc->150a70cc)
0x09489498    2,146       42,920 Foo.DataLayer.Doo
0x09488cd4    2,163       43,260 Foo.DataLayer.Daa
0x6523d7a0    2,146      120,176 System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
0x6524534c    2,173      234,684 System.Data.DataView
0x65244194    4,368      419,328 System.Data.DataSet
0x04f9a32c   10,966      482,504 System.Threading.ReaderWriterLock
0x04f9a2d4   30,735      491,760 System.WeakReference
0x6746e70c   13,048    1,043,840 System.EnterpriseServices.ServicedComponentProxy
0x094850d0    2,176    1,584,128 Foo.BusinessLayer.All
0x65242d0c   10,957    3,243,272 System.Data.DataTable
0x65244ff8  100,264   14,839,072 System.Data.DataColumn
Total 187,435 objects, Total size: 22,721,440
```

Generation 2 has 187422 finalizable objects, isn't that too much??

I am seeing a lot of OutOfMemoryException when running !dae.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are actually two important numbers in the output. *Finalizable objects* mean instances of any type that has a finalizer. A lot of those types will also implement `IDisposable` and if `Dispose` is called, then they will be garbage collected without running the finalizer (assuming `Dispose` is correctly implemented).

The other number is *ready for finalization*. This is the number of object for which their finalizer must be run prior to collection. In the output that number is 0, so there's nothing to worry about here.

As for `OutOfMemoryException` that exception is always present on the heap as it is pre-allocated by the runtime. If the exception is not thrown, you don't have to concern yourself with this.